# PHP upload file limit

Tags: php, upload

I am uploading profile images to a directory on the server. The script works fine, however I can't seem to get anything but small file size images to upload. Anything above about 2mb fails. I don't have access to the php.ini but I have added the following to htaccess with no luck. I have tried every other solution I can find online with no luck. Any ideas?

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
php_value max_input_time 400
php_value max_execution_time 400
```

Comment: Did you restart your webserver after making changes to your php.ini file?

Comment: he doesn't have access to the php.ini file

Comment: I am on a shared server and don't have access to the php.ini. I was under the impression that I could do the same with .htaccess? However, that is not working.

Comment: Ah, does ini_set() work for you? Also, take a look at step #2 and step #3 here http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#107406

Comment: @ChiragShah `upload_max_filesize` is PER_DIR, not INI_ALL

Comment: Ack! That is correct. I'm all out of ideas now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, check `phpinfo()` to see what the runtime settings are; if they still show `2M` (default), Apache is probably not obeying the .htaccess file

Normally I would tell you to make sure you have this in the virtual host declaration of your Apache configuration:

```
AllowOverride Options FileInfo
```

But being on a shared host doesn't give you those permissions (highly unlikely). You should check with your hosting provider to see whether they can raise those limits for you by adding the `php_value` settings inside your virtual host

Alternatively, work around the issue by chunking the upload files (e.g. upload 1MB at a time) as suggested by @Satya.

Comment: It says under phpinfo() upload_max_filesize 20M... so Im not sure what is going on??

Comment: You should also look at max_post_size ... which should be > 20M

Comment: Correct - it max post is 20M. But I still can't upload more then 2M

Comment: If the upload fails, you can also check `var_dump($_FILES);`

Answer (score 0):

if you can not make changes to php.ini then I am afraid you will have to try any jquery based uploaders e.g. valum or blueimp

Comment: as he is trying to upload something more than 2M , and php is denying it which can be overcome using these uploaders

Comment: but he overwrites the `php_value` in `.htaccess`

Comment: So there is nothing I can do about it via PHP without access to php.ini? I will look into the jQuery solutions